# Difference between two Riemann sums with tkz-fct

Tags: shading, tkz-fct

`tkz-fct` is great for plotting Riemann sums, but I don't see how to plot a shaded area of the difference between the sup and inf Riemann sums. I'm particularly interested in a plot with both convex and concave regions. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=-5, ymax=5]
    \tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=black, domain=0:10]{\x**(0.5) * sin(\x) + 1}
    \tkzDrawRiemannSumSup[interval=0:10, number=15]
    \tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[interval=0:10, number=15]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Inf and Sup Riemann Sums]

How does one go about shading the area between the inf and sup sums, and making the rectangles between the axis and the curve transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick.  There might be a better approach, but what I've done here is just copied the code for the two Riemann commands you used and tweaked them.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\makeatletter

\def\aeDrawRiemannSumSupInfDiff{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{%
                 \catcode`\:=12 \ae@DrawRiemannSumSupInfDiff}{\ae@DrawRiemannSumSupInfDiff[]}} 
\def\ae@DrawRiemannSumSupInfDiff[#1]{%
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{%
/tkzriemann/.cd,
interval        = 1:2,
number          = 10,
opacity         = 0.5,
line width      = 1pt}
\pgfqkeys{/tkzriemann}{#1}  
  \iftkz@init@NO%
     \FPdiv{\tkz@x@delta}{\tkz@init@xorigine}{\tkz@init@xstep}%
     \FPdiv{\tkz@y@delta}{\tkz@init@yorigine}{\tkz@init@ystep}%
  \else
     \FPset{\tkz@x@delta}{0}
     \FPset{\tkz@y@delta}{0}%
  \fi%
\FPadd\tkz@intwd{\tkz@max}{-\tkz@min}
\FPdiv\tkz@delta{\tkz@intwd}{\tkz@fct@nb}
\FPadd\tkz@fct@nb{\tkz@fct@nb}{-1}   

\begin{scope}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\tkz@fct@nb}{%
  \FPeval\x{(\tkz@min+i*\tkz@delta)}
  \FPeval\tkz@fx{\tkzFcta}
   \let\tkz@firstimg\tkz@fx
    \let\tkz@firstx\x 
  \FPadd\tkz@next{\x}{\tkz@delta}
  \let\tkzFctTmp\tkzFcta
  \FPset\x{\tkz@next}
  \FPeval\tkz@fxnext{\tkzFcta}
%\ifdim \tkz@fx pt > \tkz@fxnext pt\relax
% \draw[opacity=\tkz@fct@opacity,/tkzriemann/.cd,#1] (\tkz@firstx ,0 ) rectangle (\tkz@next , \tkz@firstimg/\tkz@init@ystep );
%\else 
%\draw[opacity=\tkz@fct@opacity,/tkzriemann/.cd,#1] (\tkz@firstx ,0 ) rectangle (\tkz@next , \tkz@fxnext/\tkz@init@ystep );
% \fi  
 \draw[opacity=\tkz@fct@opacity,/tkzriemann/.cd,#1] (\tkz@firstx , \tkz@fxnext/\tkz@init@ystep ) rectangle (\tkz@next , \tkz@firstimg/\tkz@init@ystep );
   }    
   \end{scope}  
\endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=-5, ymax=5]
  \tkzFct[line width=1pt, color=black, domain=0:10]{\x**(0.5) * sin(\x) + 1}
  \aeDrawRiemannSumSupInfDiff[fill=green,interval=0:10, number=15]
  %\tkzDrawRiemannSumInf[interval=0:10, number=15]
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason my code will not draw the graph of the function:  even when I copy and paste your code.  Nevertheless, this should be the tweak that you need.

Comment: Thanks! That seems exactly right. The graph of the function is being drawn for me. Perhaps it's a version issue?